# Suppose that every subsequence of $X=\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence that converges to $0$. Show that $\lim X= 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that every subsequence of $X=\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence that converges to $0$. Show that $\lim X= 0$.

I want to solve this question with the following **hints**:

> Prove $\varlimsup x_n$, $\varliminf x_n$ are both finite. Assume $\varlimsup x_n=l$ and $\varliminf x_n=m$. Show that $l=m=0$

I have seen it here [Suppose every subsequence of X converges to 0. Show that lim(X)=0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695273/suppose-every-subsequence-of-x-converges-to-0-show-that-limx-0)

But I want to solve as per the hint given above. Please help me. A complete solution will help me a lot.

Comment: Which part of the answer is not clear? The answer looks about as complete as it could get.

Comment: @Dominik aren't the two questions different from each other?

Comment: @OpenBall The title of the other question is misleading. The question itself is literally (!) the same.

Comment: @Dominik I want to solve as per the hint given above.

Comment: @openball  I want to solve as per the hint given above.

Comment: **Hint:** Use the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695273/suppose-every-subsequence-of-x-converges-to-0-show-that-limx-0) to show that $l=m=0$.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Would you please elaborate so that I can understand

Comment: @Dominik the answer is also misleading! (though it just needs a tiny modification)

Comment: Since $l\ge 0$ it is enough to show that $l\not>0 $. If $l>0$ then there would exist a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for all sufficiently large $k$ we would have $l>x_{n_k}>0$. But this would imply that there exists no subsequence of $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $0$, a contradiction. Hence $l=0$. Similarly you can show that $m=0$.

Comment: I don't think that the hint is a good idea. After all, the claim itself still holds in contexts where the concepts of limsup and liminf do not even exist.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ok. Then what to do?